# How mature is PyQt5 for mobile development / deployment?

Tags: qt, mobile, pyqt, qt5, pyqt5

I recently spoke with someone of 'authority' on the subject and wanted confirmation. The statement implied that there are issues with PyQt5, but they did not go into specifics. I'm wanting some expounding on whatever 'issues' there may be before we commit resources to development.

We are looking to develop and deploy several mobile apps on android, iOS primarily and will ideally include a smaller set of BB devices. Nothing with fancy graphics, just textual / message based functionality, security.

How mature is PyQt5 for Qt5 mobile? Major recurring issues with development / deployment? Any lacking features/bindings I should be aware about?

Thank you.

Comment: There is little point in asking this here, because the author of PyQt won't see it (and his opinion is the only one that really matters). Ask on the [PyQt mailing list](http://www.riverbankcomputing.com/mailman/listinfo/pyqt) instead.